# Using pygame, how can I update an object's position that is defined by a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to build the Google Dinosaur game in Python. I have

```
class Dino():
    def __init__(self, posy):
        self.score = 0
        self.isDead = False
        self.isJumping = False
        self.isDucking = False
        self.pos = (100, posy)

    def draw(self):
        dinoImport = pygame.image.load("assets\dino1.png")
        dino = pygame.transform.scale(dinoImport, (50,50))

        screen.blit(dino, self.pos)
```

Then I have the main function where the game actually runs.

```
def gameplay():

    global flag
    flag = True
    color = (255,255,255)
    y = 300
    playerDino = Dino(y)

    gamespeed = 4
    ground = Ground(-1*gamespeed)

    while flag:
        screen.fill(color)
        ground.draw()
        playerDino.draw()


        pygame.display.flip()
        events = pygame.event.get()    
       
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit() 
                exit(0) 

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
 
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
               pass
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
               y += 3
               playerDino.draw()
               
        pygame.display.update()
```

Everything is placed correctly, but when I press the w key, the y position of the dino doesn't move up by 3, it doesn't move. What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: You are only drawing is w is pressed. Is that intentional ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates of the dino are stored in a tuple on the attribute `pos`. You have to change the tuple attribute rather than `y`:

<s>`y += 3`</s>

```py
playerDino.pos = (playerDino.pos[0], playerDino.pos[1] + 3)
```

---

Anyway, I recommend to use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object for the position of the dino. You can get the rectangle form the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object, by [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect). Load the *Surface* in the constructor of `Dino`, rather than in every  frame:

```py
class Dino():
    def __init__(self, posy):
        self.score = 0
        self.isDead = False
        self.isJumping = False
        self.isDucking = False
        dinoImport = pygame.image.load("assets\dino1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(dinoImport, (50,50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (100, posy))

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

The position of `playerDino`  can be changed by changing the `rect` attribute. Your event loop wont work, because of the multiple calls [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). Since `pygame.event.get()` removes the events from the queue, the 2nd call won't return any event. Remove the first call of `pygame.event.get()`:

```py
def gameplay():
    global flag

    color = (255,255,255)
    playerDino = Dino(300)
    gamespeed = 4
    ground = Ground(-1*gamespeed)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    flag = True
    while flag:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                flag = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
               pass
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
               playerDino.rect.y += 3

        screen.fill(color)
        ground.draw()
        playerDino.draw()
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit() 
    exit(0)
```

Comment: Wow, didnt know it was that simple. Could you please explain to me how this works exactly so I can use it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @equ1nox The position of your `playerDino` is stored in variable `playerDino.pos`, which you have **initialized** with `y`, meaning it is outside of the loop and doesn't get updated every frame.  If you put `playerDino = Dino(y)` in the main loop, it should work but the solution in the answer is a better fix.

Comment: Ah ok I can see how this works. But is the "hitbox" of the dino going to be a rectangle because I am using the rect attribute. I am asking because I want to detect if the dino hits the cacti or birds, etc

Comment: @equ1nox `playerDino.rect` is the "hitbox". There is no need that the name of the attribute is "hitbox", the name "rect" is fine as well.